# NodeJS fetch() API and POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

Below is part of HTML code which allows customer to key in US Zip Code and feeling of the day.
The app will extract weather data based on Zip Code provided via API call `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={zip code},{country code}&appid={API key}`. You may refer to documentation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAOAL.png).

```
      <div class="holder zip">
        <label for="zip">Enter Zipcode here</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code here" />
      </div>
      <div class="holder feel">
        <label for="feelings">How are you feeling today?</label>
        <textarea
          class="myInput"
          id="feelings"
          placeholder="Enter your feelings here"
          rows="9"
          cols="50"
        ></textarea>
        <button id="generate" type="submit">Generate</button>
      </div>
```

Here is front end JS script <app.js> that will access to weather API, download data and store in app_info (refer to downloadAPI()). Once done, use postData() to send data to server (refer server.js below) with POST request. postData() is tag to eventListener created for "Generate" button.

```
/* Global Variables */
var app_input = "";

// variable for Zip Code
const userInput = document.getElementById("zip");
let zipCode = userInput.value;

// eventListener to update Zip Code
userInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
  zipCode = userInput.value;
  // app_input.zipCode = zipCode;
});

// variable for user feeling
const userText = document.getElementById("feelings");
let userFeedback = userText.value;

// eventListener to update user feeling
userText.addEventListener("input", function () {
  userFeedback = userText.value;
  // app_input.userFeedback = userFeedback;
});

// function to extract Weather API data
async function downloadAPI(code) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${code},us&units=metric&appid=d38ab121caf0ee2480e43210276b8001`
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  let country = data.sys.country;
  let city = data.name;
  let temperature = data.main.temp;
  let condition = data.weather[0].description;

  app_input = {
    location: `${country}, ${city}, ${zipCode}`,
    weather: `${condition}`,
    temperature: `${temperature}`,
    comment: `${userFeedback}`,
  };
}

// variable for Generate button
const form = document.getElementById("generate");

async function postData() {
  downloadAPI(zipCode);

  const response = await fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(app_input),
  });

  try {
    const appData = await response.json();
    return appData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("warning: ", error);
  }
}

// eventListener for Generate button
form.addEventListener("click", postData);
```

Below is server side code <server.js>. At the moment, I only use POST request to log the data from app_info. Will improve on this part later.

```
// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require("express");

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static("website"));

// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
const projectData = Array();

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(res.body);
});

// Setup Server
const port = 3000;

function listening() {
  console.log(`server running on localhost: ${port}`);
}

const server = app.listen(port, listening);
```

Page loaded successfully. I key in zip code: 90001 and "I feel good"; then click on "Generate" button.

Network in console shows JS successfully fetch weather data.

[image]

Error detected at app.js <Line 50 & Line 64>

[image]

which is here:

```
const response = await fetch("/", { //Error!!!
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(app_input),
  });

  try {
    const appData = await response.json();
    return appData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("warning: ", error); //Error!!!
  }
```

Please advise where did I make mistake.

Comment: Why are you using  POST, when your example url is using query params.?   btw:  `Unexpected token < in JSON ` is usually the server end sending HTML, look in your browsers network tab to see what it's returning.

Comment: @Keith can you explain further about POST and query params? I'm a beginner. BTW, I make changes to my question for better clarification. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting downloadAPI() in the postData function, and so the value of that API is not being stored in the app_info variable. Perhaps that is your issue

Comment: I updated my code and the screen shot of network in console shows my code downloaded weather API data. However, next line after downloadAPI() failed within postData() function.

Comment: try logging `response.text()` just before you do `await response.json()`. Is the response json?

Comment: Here is the text in JS console ```Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"```. Response result is HTML document. A very long HTML string start with <!DOCTYPE html> ~~~~

Comment: did you `await response.text()`? What is the status and response from the initial api call from the `fetch`? Is it in json format?

Comment: I try ```try {
    const text = await response.text();
    console.log(text);

    const appData = await response.json();
    return appData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("warning: ", error);
  }``` and result is <pre> in HTML which says ==> SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0.

Comment: just before you do your `fetch`, console log out `app_info`. I am assuming that may be an empty string which is what it is set at at the top of the script. Hence invalid json, and hence the invalid character: `"`. Let me know the result

Comment: you are right. Log out app_input within asynchronous function and it is "blank". It is weird because I manually log out app_input in console and it shows an object like this ```{location: "US, Los Angeles, 90002", weather: "haze", temperature: "26.22", comment: "Monday blue"}```. What is happening?